# something similar to permutation accuracy importance in h2o package

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o, multinomial

I fitted a random forest for my multinomial target with the `randomForest` package in R. Looking for the variable importance I found out `permutation accuracy importance` which is what I was looking for my analysis.
I fitted a random forest with the h2o package too, but the only measures it shows me are `relative_importance,  scaled_importance,  percentage`.

My question is: can I extract a measure that shows me the level of the target which better classify the variable i want to take in exam?
`Permutation accuracy importance` is the best measure I can use in this case?

For example: I have a 3 levels target: A-B-C and 5 variables: v1-v2-v3-v4-v5 Is there a measure that shows me that v1 is more important for the level A of the target rather than level B (something similiar to the permutation accuracy importance)?

Answer (score 0):

While h2o doesn't provide `permutation accuracy importance` (as you pointed out it provides variable importance) through the r/python api, you can use PDP [h2o.partialPlot()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.partialPlot.html) to see how individual levels within a feature impact the target.